# I want to write script for login functionality. There are 5 types of user for that I have written following feature file

Tags: bdd

Query: I want to login with different user for that I am parametrizing the Usertype and will verify the respective element w.r.t there access.

Now In Step file suppose eg: I have written

```
@Then ("^User logged in with \"([^\"]*)\"$)
Public void User_logged_in_with_Usertype() {
    If (Usertype= Admin){
    ...
```

So in above code in how I will get value of admin or any other user(Can we get same value from feature file or I need to write a code separately for each user)

Feature: As a user I would like to login in FMJ-Redesign application with different users

Story : User is logging in FMJ application

Scenario Outline: User is logged in with Admin user credentials

```
Given Navigating BU to "<Browser>"
When User clicks on Location
And ForevermarkJewellerWebsite element should be present on login page 
Then User logged in with "<Usertype>"
And User will check visibility of "<Element>"
Then User Logout Successfully

Examples:

|Browser  | UserType    | Element |
|Chrome   |  Admin      |         |
|Chrome   |  Market     |         |
|Chrome   |  Jeweller   |         |
|Chrome   |  Store      |         |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the value for Usertype is to have it as a parameter in the method.

Your code looks like this:

```
@Then ("^User logged in with \"([^\"]*)\"$)
Public void User_logged_in_with_Usertype() {
    If (Usertype= Admin){
        ...
```

I rewrote your Scenario outline a bit and ended up with this version

```
  Scenario Outline: User is logged in with Admin user credentials

    Given Navigating BU to <Browser>
    When User clicks on Location
    And ForevermarkJewellerWebsite element should be present on login page
    Then User logged in with <UserType>
    And User will check visibility of <Element>
    Then User Logout Successfully

    Examples:

      | Browser | UserType | Element |
      | Chrome  | Admin    |         |
      | Chrome  | Market   |         |
      | Chrome  | Jeweller |         |
      | Chrome  | Store    |         |
```

This allowed me to write the step like this:

```
@Then("^User logged in with (.*)$")
public void user_logged_in_with(String userType) throws Throwable {
    if (userType.equals("Admin")) {
        // implement our behaviour here
    }
}
```

There are a few differences to notice here:

- I removed the quotes around the parameters in the example
- I added the value of UsertType as a parameter to the method `user_logged_in_with`

These changes simplified the regular expression needed and allows you to implement different behaviour for different UserTypes.

I would probably implement four different steps for the user types you have. This would give me simpler steps, I could avoid the condition. The price would be four methods.

If I did that, the resulting implementation would look like this instead:

```
@Then("^User logged in with Admin$")
public void user_logged_in_with_Admin() throws Throwable {
    // implement our behaviour here
}
```

This simplified the regular expression even more and removed the need for a capture group.

Comment: Hi But now I am getting error message for the Usertype step as follows: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'com.digital.app.fmj.mmd.LoginFMJ.Logged_in_as_Usertype_in_FMJ() in file:/D:/AjayBackUp%20D%20Drive/Java/Cucumber_Basics/FMJ-Digital-App-Project/bin/' with pattern [^Logged in as (.*) in FMJ$] is declared with 0 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 1 arguments [Admin]. 
Step: And Logged in as Admin in FMJ

Comment: Thanks my query is resolved. Thanks for all your help.